# Is S3 base R or is it an R package?

Tags: r, oop

Hadley Wickham says [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3) that:

> S3 is R’s first and simplest OO system. It is the only OO system used in the base and stats packages...

Seemingly, if S3 is used in base R functions, then it has to be part of base R.

But if it is part of R, and not a package, then why is it not treated as part of the R language (the way the OOP functionalities of other languages are)?

S4, for instance seems to be the `methods` package, and all of the other systems for implementing OOP in R seem to separate, add-on packages.

So is S3 part of an add-on package to base R? Or is it part of base R, i.e. part of the R language?

Comment: How is it "not treated as part of the R language"?

Comment: @joran It's called "S3 OOP system" not "R's OOP system". I went to pains to explain how. Please read the question body, not just the title. Does any other language have a special name for its built-in OOP features? Not that I'm aware of. If I was aware otherwise, I wouldn't be confused.

Comment: First there was S. S had no OOP. Then R was developed as an open-source S. The first R had no OOP. S version 3 got OOP. The R team implemented S3's OOP in R. That's why it has a special name. It has retained the name because other add-on OOPs are available, as you note.

Comment: @Spacedman This is a very nice, helpful, and clarifying answer which explains the history to someone like me who never knew S -- thank you for taking my (admittedly stupid) question seriously and helping me -- I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S3 OO system is inherently part of R. A detailed explanation of how it works and behaves is included in [section 5 of the "R Language Definition" manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Object_002doriented-programming)